# unable to load the new url to the href attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to change the href attribute of all anchor tags using $.each function.
I can get the new href in the console, but when clicked on the elements it doesn't redirects to the new url changed.

```
$(".section-icons").each(function () {
    var newHref = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    newHref += "?currentMod=sales_target";
    console.log(newHref);
    $(this).find("a").attr("href", newHref);
});

<div class="section-icons">
    <a href="sales-target-revenue-wise.php">
        <div class="modules-icons-dd">
            <img src="<?=$dir_path?>images/module-icons/sales-target-revenue-wise-icon.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="section-text">Revenue Wise Sales Target</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".section-icons").each(function () {
        var newHref = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        newHref += "?currentMod=sales_target";
        console.log(newHref);
        $(this).find("a").attr("href", newHref);
    });
});
```

You need to do it after the DOM is ready.

Also, your script needs to be wrapped inside `<script></script>`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/b6w8T/)

Comment: I can say that because he hasn't wrapped it in the question. Why would anyone in their right mind strip their code and paste only part of that code on SO?

Comment: @amit true. This thing works well.
but the same doesn't work when bootstrap stuffs are also being used :(